# PayPal API: get Topic/Message of Transaction

Tags: api, paypal, transactions, message, title

How do i get the name of the Transaction in the PayPal-Transaction? For Example: the Messagefield in PayPal when you send Money or the Name of the Ebay Title if you buy something
Current request works, iam getting all fields accept a title/message for each transaction
My current CODE

```
     <?php
     $info = 'USER=pp2_api1.fdd.com'
    .'&PWD=s8LW9QSdsdQ'fdgfQ49BGnB2EtG7ZgE.-sgUqA1s-RyHsMfsFrssUOnsREbod1'
    .'&METHOD=TransactionSearch'
    .'&TRANSACTIONCLASS=RECEIVED'
    .'&STARTDATE=2013-01-08T05:38:48Z'
    .'&ENDDATE=2013-07-14T05:38:48Z'
    .'&VERSION=94';

    $curl = curl_init('https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp');
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok works just with "GetTransactionDetails"